# Keep Calendar's events alive in Notification Centre, until user sees them (independently of the "end" time)

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, calendar

Is there any way to keep alive in "Notification Centre", each Calendar event, until the user sees it?

The current state is, that if the "End" time passes, the event disappears and I never get informed of that event.
It's important for me, when I set an event (by default), to get informed for that event, independently of the end time.
Tbh: I don't want end time at all :)

Model name: iPhone 13 /
iOS version: 16.3.1